# Find a file by pattern but ignore others with similar patterns

Tags: find, file-management

I have a directory that has subdirectories in it and I need to get the names of some of these subdirectories but there is one with a similar pattern as them that I want to ignore.

For example, if the list of Subdirectories is like this:

```
Name_One
Not_needed1
Name_Two
Name_Three
Not_needed2
Name_Zero
```

I want to store the names of the subdirectories Name_One, Name_Two, and Name_Three in variables but I want to ignore Name_0.

Also, the naming changes with each project but always follows the pattern of Name_Number and Name_Zero is always the one that needs to be excluded.

I am using Mac OS.

Comment: Please give _actual_ examples because any solution will need to depend on the precise names involved.

Comment: Also, please tell us what operating system you are using since there are many different `find` implementations out there.

Comment: I'm using Mac OS. The names them selves will be changing with each project this is run for. Meaning Name_One, Name_Two, Name_Three will always start with Name_ but the number after can change. However, Name_Zero will always be Name_Zero and always need to be excluded.

Comment: Please don't answer in comments, [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/672109/edit) your original question instead. That way the relevant details are readily available without the need to dig them out from comments. It's a good idea to check the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) of every new community you join, as things like data you should provide in the question differ depending on the focus of the community. [From Review](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/390620)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
find . -type d -name 'Name_*' ! -name 'Name_Zero'
```

for the directories name of `Name_[digit]` and exclude only directory `Name_0`.

```
find . -type d ! -name 'Name_0' -regex './Name_[0-9]*'
```

in case you had subdirectors too, use this:

```
find . -type d ! -name 'Name_0' -regex '.*/Name_[0-9]*'
```

the regex above matches the directories' name where it matches pattern `Name_[zero-or-more-digits]`, to avoid to match on `Name_`, use `'.*/Name_[0-9][0-9]*'` instead.